# Creating External Tables in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, external-tables

Is it possible to create external table in Snowflake referring to on premise Oracle database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Snowflake does not presently support [query federation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_database_system) to other DBMS software.

[External tables in Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external.html) exist only to expose a collection of data files (commonly found in data-lake architectures) as a qualified table without requiring [a load first](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html).

Querying your Oracle tables will currently require an [explicit export](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/generating-csv-files) of its data onto a cloud storage location to allow Snowflake to access it.